# I recieve this error when i compile my java file: This method must return a result of type String

Tags: java

[code source:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErbnX.png)

i try both return and System.out.println() but nothing have changed,help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... The error is just telling you that the method *must always* return a string.  What does the method currently return if the loop is never entered?  Nothing at all.  Add a `return` statement (or throw an exception) after the loop.

Comment: Additionally, I think you meant to put your `return null;` after the loop rather than inside it. Currently it will only check the first element with the conditional statement and either return the value or null. It won’t check any other elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return `null` only if no number is found. So move the `return null` in line 49 to line 51 after the `}` of the for-loop.

The posted code never reaches `i=1`, because the loop always returns in the first iteration.

The error tells you, that cases exists where the method ends without a `return` statement. This is the case if `cpt=0`, for example.